# Simple html dom with wordpress

Tags: wordpress, simple-html-dom

i would like to use html simple dom width wordpress. The problem is when i add :

```
require('../wp-blog-header.php');
```

The script return an error: `Fatal error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object in /home/labonnevisite/www/simpledom/simple_html_dom.php on line 1113`

When i delete: `require('../wp-blog-header.php');` my script works fine

This is my script:

```
require('../wp-blog-header.php'); require_once 'simple_html_dom.php';

$html->load_file('http://www.urlofwebsite.com'); 
foreach($html->find('a.name') as $e) { $link = $e->href; echo $link . '<br>'; }
```

Comment: Do the requires in the other order? 

First simple_html_dom.php and then wp-blog-header.php

Comment: The same error if i change the order unfortunately

Comment: Why do you include your header like that? Why not get_header() or whatever it is standard in Wordpress? Maybe try including the simple_html_dom library through functions.php file, I think this is what it's meant to be for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
include('../wp-blog-header.php');
```

or to include the header using built-in Wordpress functions:

```
get_header(); // get_header( $name )
```

Wordpress also has some built-in functionality for including common components:

```
get_header()
get_footer()
get_sidebar()
get_template_part()
get_search_form()
comments_template()
```

More information in the codex:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Include_Tags

Answer (score 0):

This might be a *little* late, but better later then never?

In order to use

```
$html->load_file(...)
```

you need to initialize the html-object first, like this:

```
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file(...)
```